# Focus and Blur on dynamic inputs not working correctly

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input

I'm trying to make a simple OTP input where you have 6 individual inputs and when user enters one number, it automatically moves to next input. I have a simple JS file which dynamically creates and appends the inputs to a HTML form. But it seems when I try to `blur` the selected input and `focus` the next input it doesn't work.

```js
for (let i = 0; i < OTP_LENGTH; ++i) {
  const input = document.createElement('input');
  input.setAttribute('max-length', '1');
  input.type = 'number';
  input.setAttribute('id', 'otp-input');
  input.setAttribute('data-otp-pos', i);
  textInputs.push(input);
  otpContainer.appendChild(input);
  input.onfocus = () => console.log("Focus", i);
  input.onblur = () => console.log("Blur", i);
  input.onchange = (e) => {
    const target = e.target;
    const position = parseInt(target.dataset.otpPos, 10);
    if (position !== OTP_LENGTH - 1) {
      console.log('Focussing', textInputs[position + 1]);
      target.blur();
      const nextInput = textInputs[position + 1];
      nextInput.click();
      nextInput.focus();
      // textInputs[position + 1].focus();
    }
  };

}
```

But when i click outside of the input then the `focus` event and `blur` events are fired and it works.

Complete code available on the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/gr24hufp/1/

I tried doing `body.focus()`, `nextInput.click()` etc but nothing works

Comment: Changing `onchange` to `onkeyup` seems to make it work. I'm not sure why it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `change` event is not fired when a user edits the contents of an input text field - it is fired when that field loses focus after being edited, e.g. because the user has clicked out of the field.

Your code should work if you use the `input` event instead which fires every time the value of an input field changes, or `keyup` as you say :)

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event